# C# Calling a Method in Containing Class

Tags: c#, events

I have a page with 2 web controls that intentionally have no knowledge of each other. Each control also has its own helper class to take care of events and such. Only 1 of the controls (`EditBox`) has a "save" button on it and when it saves, it needs to grab data from the other control (`MceEditorAlpha`) on the page, how do I do this?
The `MceEditorAlpha` control has `SaveMessage()` on it which will retrieve data from the `EditBox` control and save it in its helper class object, however, I don't know how to call `SaveMessage()` from the helper class.

Here is the control that *does not* have a save button on it.

```
    public partial class MceEditorAlpha : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
      public MceEditor Mce { get; set; }

      public void SaveMessage()
      {
          if (Mce == null)
              Mce = new MceEditor();
          Mce.Text = tbDescription.Text;
      }
    }
```

Now, in the helper class for `MceEditorAlpha` I have an event handler that fires when the "save" button on the `EditBox` control is pressed.  What I need to do is get this event to trigger `SaveMessage()` in the class listed above.  Do I have to create an event in `MceEditor` and a handler in `MceEditorAlpha` above?

```
    public class MceEditor : IMessageBroadcaster
    {
      public string Text { get; set; }

      public void OnEditBoxSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          //Handle the event from the EditBoxSave "save" button_click
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as i see it MceEditorAlpha has a referrence to MceEditor. To be able to recieve notifications from it make MceEditor expose a OnSave event and subsribe to it from MceEditorAlpha

Comment: Sounds good, I'm working on that now. I guess I've never really made and event handler that simply fires another event before.